# Highscore, die (Feminin)

Tags: gender, anglicism

Eigentlich wollte ich nur nachschlagen, was zum Wort *Highscore* im Duden steht, doch dann wurde ich überrascht. Dort steht als erstes Ergebnis in der Suche:

> [Highscore, die](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Highscore_Punktwertung_Tabelle)

Im Artikel sehe ich keine Anmerkung, jedoch in der URL: Punktwertung, Tabelle.

Ich stimme vollkommen damit überein, dass *Highscoretabelle* feminin ist; das liegt daran, dass im Deutschen bei zusammengesetzten Substantiven das jeweils letzte Wort das Ausschlaggebende ist.

Es gibt noch einen zweiten Artikel

> [Highscore, der](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Highscore_Punktwert)

auf den auch der erste unter Bedeutung verlinkt.

Hat jemand schon mal dieses Geschlecht bei *Highscore* gesehen oder handelt es sich bei diesem Eintrag um einen einfachen Fehler?

Comment: Ich hab das so noch nie gehört, aber nach einem guten Spielverlauf ist laut Duden wohl denkbar dass jemand seinen neuen Highscore in die Highscore einträgt. (Ich würde das selbst nur ohne Objekt formulieren, aber vielleicht haben ja diejenigen, die besonders häufig einen Highscore eintragen bzw. den Vorgang sprachlich zu beschreiben und zu kommunizieren pflegen, ein anderes Verhältnis zu diesem Phänomen)

Comment: Ich kenne nur `der Highscore`. Ich habe den neuen Highscore in den Highscore eingetragen.

Comment: Ich würde "in die Highscore-s; in den Highscores" sagen, ein einfacher Plural des Maskulin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Schade, dass du kein Beispiel für die Verwendung des Begriffs "Highscore" vorgelegt hast. Das hätte vermutlich Klarheit gebracht. Denn hier wird "Highscore" offenbar in zwei verschiedenen Bedeutungen verwendet:

**Der Highscore** (maskulin)
Das ist der höchste Einzelwert, der bei einem Wettbewerb erreicht wurde. Verwendung: "Der Highscore liegt bei 8527 Punkten." Bedeutung: "Die höchste Punktezahl die erreicht wurde beträgt 8527 Punkte."
Der Highscore kann aber auch die persönliche Bestleistung eines Teilnehmers, der mehrfach bewertet wurde, bedeuten. Dann ist der Highscore der beste Wert, den ein bestimmter Teilnehmer erreicht hat. Aber auch in dieser Bedeutung handelt es sich um einen einzelnen Wert, nicht um eine Menge mehrerer Werte.

**Die Highscore-Liste** (feminin, weil die Liste feminin ist)
Das ist eine absteigend sortierte Liste mit den jeweils besten Ergebnissen der besten Teilnehmer. Sie enthält mehrere verschiedene Werte, muss aber nicht notwendigerweise die Werte aller Teilnehmer enthalten, sondern nur die besten 5 (10, 20, ...) Werte. Jeder Teilnehmer ist in dieser Liste nur einmal vertreten, nämlich mit seinem persönlichen Highscore. Offenbar wird "die Highscore-Liste" auch verkürzt verwendet:

**Die Highscore** (feminin)
Synonym für "Die Highscore-Liste". Verwendung: "Gestern habe ich es in die Highscore geschafft, ich bin jetzt auf Platz 9." Bedeutung: "Ich habe es unter die besten Zehn geschafft, ich bin jetzt auf Platz 9."

**Highscore als Kompositum von "high" und "Score"**
Das Wort "Score", das laut Wiktionary übrigens nicht englischen, sondern französischen Ursprungs ist, bedeutet "Spielstand" oder "Punktezahl" und wird laut Wiktionary in der deutschen Sprache ausschließlich als männliches Wort verwendet: Der Score
siehe http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/score

Der Duden führt als Herkunftssprachen zwar Mittelenglisch und Altnordisch an, lässt bei "Score" aber auch nur den männlichen Artikel zu: Der Score
siehe http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Score

"Highscore" als Kompositum muss das Geschlecht des letzten Bestandteiles erhalten, und da dies das männliche Wort "Score" ist, muss auch der Highscore männlich sein.

Ein Score (nicht: "eine Score"!) ist ein einzelner Wert, keine Liste mehrerer Werte. Der Highscore ist unter allen Scores der höchste.

---

Ich halte aber auch regionale Unterschiede für möglich. Ich bin Österreicher und habe die weibliche Form "die Highscore" bis gerade eben noch nie in meinem 48 Jahre andauernden Leben gehört oder gelesen.

Wenn ich über die Liste der besten Werte sprechen würde, würde ich folgende Begriffe verwenden:

- die Top 10 (plural!)
- die Highscore-Liste (feminin singular)

---

Als dritte Möglichkeit halte ich es für denkbar, dass "die Highscore" im Sinn von "die Bestenliste" unter jüngeren Sprechern verbreiteter ist als unter älteren.

Comment: "Jeder Teilnehmer ist in dieser Liste nur einmal vertreten, nämlich mit seinem persönlichen Highscore."; "Der Highscore ist unter allen Scores der höchste." - zumindest im Bereich von Computerspielen scheint das nicht dem tatsächlichen Sprachgebrauch zu entsprechen, wo "die Highscores" vielmehr die (10, 20, ...) höchsten erreichten Punktzahlen erreichen und (insbesondere auf Privatrechnern) nicht selten auch denselben Spieler mehrfach (bzw. überhaupt nur einen Spieler auf sämtlichen Positionen) enthalten.

Answer (score 0):

`Highscore` ist der höchste Wert. Eingedeutscht haben sich sowohl Feminium und Maskulinum eingebürgert. (Welches Häufiger ist? Keine Ahnung.)

Die Menge der (n) höchsten Werte sind `die Highscores` oder `die Highscoreliste`.

Das bedeutet, der Verweis auf `der Highscore` ist völlig in Ordnung, aber der der Inhalt im Eintrag zu `die Highscore` ist falsch. Wer weiß, wem der Dudenverlag da auf den Mund geschaut hat.

Comment: Du sagst im ersten Satz, dass sich sowohl Femininum als auch Maskulinum eingedeutscht haben und dann am Ende, dass der Eintrag zu `die Highscore` falsch ist, das widerspricht sich.

Comment: Nein, weil ich nicht die Existenz des Eintrags meine, sondern den Inhalt des Eintrags. Ist vielleicht missverständlich. Werde ich ändern.

Comment: Naja, besonders viel Inhalt, der falsch ein kann, steht in dem Eintrag ja garnicht. Eigentlich nichts bis auf das Geschlecht.

Comment: @kelunik Doch, nämlich dass `die highscore` die Highscoreliste bezeichnen würde.

Comment: Ja, eben das hab ich noch nie gehört, hast du da Informationen in welcher Region sich das eingebürgert hat?

Comment: Ich kenne `die Highscore` für die Highscorliste eher als Soziolekt denn als Dialekt.

Comment: Ich habe noch nie "die Highscore" in irgendeinem Kontext gehört.