# Warum ist "Bill of Rights" feminin?

Tags: noun, gender, loanword

Ich habe gesehen, dass die amerikanische "Bill of Rights" laut [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_of_Rights_(Vereinigte_Staaten)) feminin ist und musste mich fragen, warum das so ist. Die meisten von anderen Sprachen stammenden Wörter sind sächlich und die Bill of Rights ist ein Gesetz und das ist auf Deutsch auch sächlich. Vielleicht wäre die Antwort von manchen "es ist einfach so", aber wenn so, werden alle Deutschen das richtige Genus benutzen?

Eine andere Frage: Wie kann man das Genus von solchen Wörtern herausfinden? Im Duden sind solche Wörter nicht zu finden, und Wikipedia ist nicht wirklich autoritativ.

Comment: related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5545/for-new-words-which-are-often-nouns-who-sets-the-gender

Comment: Die meisten Substantive aus anderen Sprachen sind maskulin (generisches Maskulinum). Bei Wikipedia finde ich zur engl. Bill of Rights 'Gesetzesvorlage der Rechte' (die Vorlage), bei der am.: 'Zusatzartikel zur Verfassung'. Beides ist feminin.

Comment: Ähnlich: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4714/how-is-the-gender-of-new-words-established (englisch), https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/44/do-latin-loanwords-conserve-their-gender (englisch), https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/928/wonach-richtet-sich-das-geschlecht-eines-anglizismus (deutsch); zu einzelnen Ausdrücken: [Virus](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2735/what-gender-has-a-virus), [Highscore](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8493/highscore-die-feminin), [Quest](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/11348/welches-geschlecht-hat-quest)

Comment: Für die andere Frage im Nachtrag: [Wonach richtet sich das Geschlecht eines Anglizismus?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/928) Ich würde dir nahelegen, den Teil zu entfernen.

Comment: Die Urkunde? Die Verfassung? Beides irgendwo naheliegend.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Für das Genus von Fremdwörtern gibt es keine verbindlichen Regeln, sondern nur Anhaltspunkte, die mal das eine, mal das andere nahelegen. Wenn sich zwei solche Anhaltspunkte widersprechen, kann es auch durchaus ein paar Jahrzehnte zwei korrekte Geschlechter geben, bis sich eines allgemein durchgesetzt hat. Zum Beispiel ist *crêpe* im Französischen feminin und deshalb *die Crêpe* richtig. (Anhaltspunkt: Genus in der Ursprungssprache.) Andererseits ist eine Crêpe einfach nur ein dünner Pfannkuchen, und deshalb auch *der Crêpe* richtig. (Anhaltspunkt: Genus verwandter deutscher Wörter.)

Im Fall von *Bill* sprechen folgende Anhaltspunkte für feminin:

- Es gibt ein verwandtes deutsches Wort *die Bulle*, ebenfalls abgeleitet von lateinisch *bulla/billa*; beide sind feminin.
- In der häufigen Anwendung auf Geldscheine (*dollar bill*) wurde *bill* früher in der Regel mit *die Note, die Geldnote* übersetzt. (Heute verwendet man eher *Geldschein*, aber in Zusammensetzungen immer noch *Note*: *Dollarnote*.)

Der Online-Duden hat durchaus [einen Eintrag für *Bill*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Bill_Bulle_Gesetzentwurf), dem man auch das Genus entnehmen kann.

PS: Wie die Edit-History dieser Antwort und die Diskussion dazu zeigt, gibt es auch bei deutschen Muttersprachlern manchmal Unsicherheit über das Genus eines Worts. Davon sind auch nicht immer nur Fremdwörter betroffen. In manchen Familien hat ein Wort ein anderes Genus als im Duden; es gibt aber auch Unterschiede, die sich im Duden niederschlagen, darunter regionale Abweichungen. Diese scheinen besonders häufig zwischen deutschem und österreichischem Deutsch aufzutreten.

PPS: In meiner Antwort kommen nicht alle Arten von Anhaltspunkten vor, die eine Rolle spielen können. Eine wichtige, die noch fehlt, sind Klassen von gleichartigen Substantiven, die in der Regel dasselbe Genus haben. Eine Aufzählung vieler solcher Klassen gibt es z.B. [hier](http://donnerwetter.kielikeskus.helsinki.fi/DVG/Subst/Subst-Regeln/Genus/deutsch.htm). Beispiele: Himmelsrichtungen sind maskulin, Bäume meist feminin und Metalle meist Neutra.

Besonders häufig ist, glaube ich, Unklarheit darüber, ob ein Wort maskulin oder neutral ist. Den Unterschied kann man schon in der Schriftsprache nicht immer erkennen. In der Umgangssprache kann er dann noch weiter verwischen. („Für mich bitte auch ein’ Crêpe, aber zu meinem Crêpe Apfelmus“ klingt, als wäre *Crêpe* neutral.)

Comment: @Gerhard _das Krepp(papier)_ spricht gegen Neutrum für die französischen Pfannkuchen (Unterscheidung von Homonymen durch Genus). Kurzer Vokal und einfacher Auslaut in einem einsilbigen Wort sprechen auch eher für Maskulinum als für Femininum – wie bei _Bill_, wo ich auch der heute fast unbekannten _Bulle_ die Genusverantwortung zuschreiben würde.

Comment: Ich möchte anmerken, das »neutral« weder eine deutsche, noch eine fachsprachliche Bezeichnung für ein grammatisches Geschlecht ist. Üblich sind diese Trippel: »männlich, weiblich, *sächlich*« oder (für Deutsch) »maskulin, feminin, *neutrum*« (In anderen Sprachen gibt es noch weitere Geschlechter mit anderen Namen, z.B. »utrum« in Schwedisch)

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast: Das sehe ich anders, und [der Duden auch](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/neutral) (Bedeutung 4). Deine Bearbeitung ist daher eine Verschlimmbesserung, weil jetzt lateinische und deutsche Begriffe durcheinandergehen.

Comment: @Crissov Interessantes Argument (*`Unterscheidung von Homonymen durch Genus`*), klingt für mich völlig logisch. Deswegen würde z.B. *`der Bill`* rausfallen, oder?

Comment: @Wolf Ja, das kann auch bei _Bill_ durchaus ein Teilgrund sein. Gerade bei Namen würde ich dieses Phänomen aber nicht überbewerten wollen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: *Neutrum* ist ein Substantiv, *neutral* ist das zugehörige Adjektiv. Ein Adjektiv *neutrum* (klein geschrieben) hab ich im Online-Duden auf Anhieb nicht gefunden. Möglicher Grund für die Verwirrung: "Das Schiff ist Neutrum (nicht: neutrum), so wie der Mann Kapitän ist."

Comment: Ich habe [die meisten Kommentare in den Chat verschoben](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30083/discussion-on-answer-by-hans-adler-warum-ist-bill-of-rights-feminin).

Comment: *neutrum* vs. *sächlich* vs. *neutral* bietet sich doch geradezu für eine eigene Frage hier an. Ich habe leider gerade nicht die Zeit und Muße, sie zu stellen. (@HubertSchölnast)

Answer (score 0):

Eine Ergänzung zu user2183:

Außerdem gibt es das Wort [Unbill](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Unbill). Der Duden gibt als Genus feminin, maskulin oder Neutrum an; in dieser Reihenfolge.

Verwandt ist das Wort nicht mit bulla, sondern mit billig, Bild.